# Using BULK COLLECT with LIMIT clause

Tags: mysql

I am a beginner....just want to know why this following script is giving error while compiling.your replies will be helpful

```
create or replace procedure fetch_employee
is 
    cursor test_departments_cur
    is 
      select * from test_departments;

    Type test_departments_aat is
    table of test_departments_cur%ROWTYPE
    INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

    l_test_departments test_departments_aat;

 Begin
  open test_departments_cur;
  loop
    fetch test_departments_cur
    bulk collect into l_test_departments limit 10;

    exit when l_test_departments.count=0;

    for i in 1..l_test_departments.count
    loop
    dbms_output.put_line(l_test_departments(i));
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line('=============================================');
  end loop;

  close test_departments_cur;
end   fetch_employee;
```

Its showing error: `Error(23,5): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PUT_LINE'`

```
in 
 dbms_output.put_line(l_test_departments(i));
```

Please answer

Answer (score 0):

"l_test_departments" is an array of type "test_departments_aat" which is holding a record. As its type is "test_departments_cur%rowtype" , so to access a cursor's value ,you need to pass the column of the cursor as follows :

```
 dbms_output.put_line(l_test_departments(i).<column_name>);
```

Hope this helps.